# Ícono en página web no carga

Tags: css, html5

No entiendo por qué no me carga el ícono si ya lo pasé a formato .ico y está dentro de la carpeta de imágenes del mismo proyecto. No entiendo por qué no carga. No agregué código porque no es largo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ami me sirvió agregar el atributo `type="image/x-icon"` Saludos

Comment: ¿Dónde está el .ico en ralación a index.html?

Comment: usa Google Chrome y fíjate que error te tira en la consola

Comment: ponlo en el directorio raiz, si no lo muestra ahí, debes revisar el formato de tu imagen, no puedes poner cualquier imagen debe ser standard .

Answer (score 0):

prueba agregando el tipo de imagen

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/simboloweb.ico">
```

Comment: No, tampoco, me reconoce la propiedad type pero e; image/x-icon no... :(

Answer (score 0):

Debe ser un problema de rutas, intenta revisar bien el nombre del archivo y las rutas que estás trabajando. También puede ser caché, podrías probar limpiarlo en tu navegador. Por último, revisa tu código fuente en el browser, y ver si en los recursos está cargando el favicon o la consola te arroja algún error, usando el inspeccionador de elementos.

Por otro lado, no es completamente necesario que el formato sea `.ico`, también puedes usar `.png`. Puedes ver más información [aquí](https://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon)